# How to custome the request URL for favicon.ico. And the favicon.ico did not load correctly

Tags: html, reactjs, favicon

I am using react to build my web page. I placed my favicon.ico in my public/img folder. And the href of favicon.ico has set to /img/favicon.ico. But the favicon can not be load. After I check the favicon.ico request url in Chrome it is still http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico. I want the request url be http://localhost:3000/img/favicon.ico

This is my code for icon link

```
<head>
...
<link ref="icon" href="/img/favicon.icon" type="image/x-icon">
...
</head>
```

Very thanks

Comment: It's `<link rel="icon">` **not** `<link ref="icon">`.

Comment: Also, `/img/favicon.icon` is not `/img/favicon.ico`.

Comment: Also, it's conventional to always serve the favicon from `/favicon.ico` for the benefit of pages that lack the `<link rel="icon">` element, as most browsers will _always_ check `/favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <head>
>     <link ref="icon" href="/img/favicon.icon" type="image/x-icon">
> </head>
> ```

There's a few things wrong with your above code:

- It's `<link rel="icon">` not `<link ref="icon">`.
- Your post says the filename is `favicon.ico`, not `favicon.icon`, so correct the file-extension in the `href` attribute: `href="/img/favicon.ico"`.
- Also, it's conventional to always serve the favicon from `/favicon.ico` for the benefit of pages that lack the `<link rel="icon">` element, as most browsers will always check `/favicon.ico`.
- Also, only use `type="image/x-icon"` (or `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`) if the file **actually is** a Win32 `.ico` file (which contains multiple images at different sizes). If the file is actually a single-frame `.png` image or similar then use `image/png` or whatever the type is.

So you should have:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```